# How to get just the text from a ComboBox SelectedItem?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, powershell

I made a WPF GUI in visual studio, and am manipulating it with PowerShell. I'm currently working out how to change data with the GUI elements, and am getting stuck on the a ComboBox. Here's the relevant code:

```
$testVar=$WPFcombobox.SelectedItem.ToString()
Write-Host $testVar;
```

And here's the output:

> System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: test123

I want to get back just

> test123

I also tried `$testVar=$WPFcombobox.SelectedItem`

but got the same result.

I also tried `$testVar=$WPFcombobox.SelectedItem.Text.`

and get nothing. If I add `.ToString()` after that, I get a "null-value" error.

I know I could just make a new variable and chop off the irrelevant part, but if there's a better way to get my desired output I would rather just do that.

Comment: ["ComboBox.Text Property - Gets or sets the text of the currently selected item."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.text(v=vs.110).aspx) ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I'm using PowerShell. Your link is for C#, C++, F#, and VB.

Comment: does your PowerShell use a different .Net framework to C#, C++, F# and VB? Mine doesn't.

Comment: I guess not. What was I supposed to get from the link then? I tried calling "TextProperty" in various ways, but just got errors.

Comment: I think what @TessellatingHeckler was hinting at, is that the property you want to check is called `Text` so instead of checking the `SelectedItem` property have a look at what you get with `Text` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$WPFComboBox` is the name of your control:

```
$TestVar = $WPFComboBox.Text
Write-Host $TestVar
```

No need to find the selected item. The selected item's value is assigned "automatically" to the `ComboBox.Text` property.

Comment: Ah! So the same as with a TextBox. I feel silly. Thank you!